# Map parts turn white when exporting image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, image

When I try and export an image or map now from Print Layout, instead of creating a clean image, random white blocks appear over the image, as seen in image attached. Any thoughts as to what is creating the problem / solving it beyond reinstallation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please attach the image you mentioned.

Comment: Your image is from a WMS service?